# Parsing a String Too Long for Charindex

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, charindex

In TSQL (SSMS 2016), I'm trying to parse recurring data from a long string using a WHILE loop, temporary tables, and CHARINDEX. Each time the loop runs, it uses the previous stopping point as the next starting point. The loop works but CHARINDEX seems to have an 8000 character limit and the string is a lot longer than that. Is there another way to parse data from a string longer than 8000 characters?

**EDIT** - I'm trying to extract names indicated by attribute tags from a long string (over 100,000 characters). The data looks something like this but concatenated into one long string:

```
<alarm-response-list xmlns="http://www.thePlace.com" total-alarms="862" throttle="862" error="EndOfResults">
    <alarm-responses>
        <alarm id="5afeeaac-355f-11a0-02bd-0080101c40b8">
            <attribute id="0x12d7f">##.##.###.###</attribute>
            <attribute id="0x1006e">Narnia</attribute>
        </alarm>
        <alarm id="5b5724cb-e0be-1016-0275-0080101c40b8">
            <attribute id="0x12d7f">##.##.###.###</attribute>
            <attribute id="0x1006e">Mordor</attribute>
        </alarm>
        <alarm id="5b4af6e5-8f8d-103e-023d-0080101c40b8">
            <attribute id="0x12d7f">##.##.###.###</attribute>
            <attribute id="0x1006e">Atlantis</attribute>
        </alarm>
```

In this example, I would want anything with attribute id "0x1006e".

**EDIT** - Please see sample code below. The code runs fine so long as the WHILE statement is limited by a number less than 8000. After that, the CHARINDEX of limit of 8000 characters kicks in.

```
    DECLARE @temp TABLE(modelName VARCHAR(300))
    DECLARE @ctr INT = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM [dbo].[Alarms])
    DECLARE @start INT = (SELECT CHARINDEX('1006E',Results)+7 FRP FROM [dbo]. 
   [Alarms] WHERE ID = @ctr) 
    DECLARE @len INT = (SELECT  
    CHARINDEX('</attr',Results,CHARINDEX('1006E',Results)) - 
    CHARINDEX('1006E',Results) - 7 FROM [dbo].[Alarms] WHERE ID = @ctr)
    DECLARE @totalLen INT = (SELECT LEN(CAST(results AS VARCHAR(MAX))) FROM 
    dbo.Alarms WHERE ID = @ctr)

    WHILE @start < 5000 BEGIN
    INSERT @temp 
    SELECT SUBSTRING(Results,@start,@len) Name 

     FROM [dbo].[Alarms]
     WHERE ID = @ctr

    SET @start = (SELECT CHARINDEX('1006E',Results,@start + 1)+7 FRP FROM [dbo]. 
    [Alarms] WHERE ID = @ctr) 
    SET @len = (SELECT  
    CHARINDEX('</attr',Results,CHARINDEX('1006E',Results,@start+1)) -
          CHARINDEX('1006E',Results,@start + 1) - 7 FROM [dbo].[Alarms] WHERE ID 
    = @ctr)

    END

    Select * from @temp
```

Comment: Declare the string as `VARCHAR(max)`.

Comment: A while loop seems inefficient and there may be a better/faster way to do it.  If you post your code we can take a look and provide better feedback

Comment: If you are using a while to parse a string I would suggest you need a better approach. Try any of the approaches here. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: In 2016 there is built in split string function:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: A SMALL sample and desired results would be helpful.  Parsing is a rather ambiguous term.

Comment: From @nicky: From your query what I could understand is if you declare string as VARCHAR(MAX) will    help.
 Else if you share a small sample of your code will be helpful.

Comment: @JamesPratt there are a *lot* of duplicate questions that show how to split strings, if that's what you want. Using loops is probably the slowest way to do it. The fastest methods use XML or a SQLCLR function

Comment: Good day James, you should think about using SQLCLR for this requirement.

Comment: I added sample data and the query.

Comment: The real issue here is using a loop to split a string. See the article I posted and forget doing this with a loop.

Comment: Your sample provides square brackets (`[blah]`), while your code looks for `'</attr'`... Are you trying to parse XML with string methods? This might be done better...

Comment: I updated the description with data that accurately reflects the format of what I'm working with.

Comment: please avoid chameleon questions... After your edit this is something else entirely and invalidating existing answers... For the future: If you find the need to change a question it is better to close the existing question by accepting the best answer (the one which answers the initial question). Then start a new question.

Comment: Apologies. This is the first question I've posted on this site. I will try to be more thorough at the start in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add this as a new answer.

As stated in comment:
please avoid chameleon questions... After your edit this is something else entirely and invalidating existing answers... For the future: If you find the need to change a question it is better to close the existing question by accepting the best answer (the one which answers the initial question). Then start a new question.

### Solve your issue with native XML's methods

James, your *string* is nothing ridiculous, nothing you have to parse, but just XML. There are existing tools to read this. Almost any programming language will provide support for `XPath` and `XQuery`. This is nothing you should do on your own...

Try it out and come back with any issues (but in a new question)

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<alarm-response-list xmlns="http://www.thePlace.com" total-alarms="862" throttle="862" error="EndOfResults">
    <alarm-responses>
        <alarm id="5afeeaac-355f-11a0-02bd-0080101c40b8">
            <attribute id="0x12d7f">##.##.###.###</attribute>
            <attribute id="0x1006e">Narnia</attribute>
        </alarm>
        <alarm id="5b5724cb-e0be-1016-0275-0080101c40b8">
            <attribute id="0x12d7f">##.##.###.###</attribute>
            <attribute id="0x1006e">Mordor</attribute>
        </alarm>
        <alarm id="5b4af6e5-8f8d-103e-023d-0080101c40b8">
            <attribute id="0x12d7f">##.##.###.###</attribute>
            <attribute id="0x1006e">Atlantis</attribute>
        </alarm>

<!-- have to append closing nodes -->

    </alarm-responses>
</alarm-response-list>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.thePlace.com')
SELECT @xml.value('(/alarm-response-list/@total-alarms)[1]','int') AS TotalAlarms
      ,@xml.value('(/alarm-response-list/@throttle)[1]','int') AS throttle
      ,@xml.value('(/alarm-response-list/@error)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS error
      ,alarm.value('@id','uniqueidentifier') AS Alarm_id
      ,attr.value('@id','nvarchar(max)') AS Alarm_Attribute_id
      ,attr.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Alarm_Attribute_content
FROM @xml.nodes('/alarm-response-list/alarm-responses/alarm') A(alarm)
OUTER APPLY alarm.nodes('attribute') B(attr);
```

The result

```
+-------------+----------+--------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------+-------------------------+
| TotalAlarms | throttle | error        | Alarm_id                             | Alarm_Attribute_id | Alarm_Attribute_content |
+-------------+----------+--------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------+-------------------------+
| 862         | 862      | EndOfResults | 5AFEEAAC-355F-11A0-02BD-0080101C40B8 | 0x12d7f            | ##.##.###.###           |
+-------------+----------+--------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------+-------------------------+
| 862         | 862      | EndOfResults | 5AFEEAAC-355F-11A0-02BD-0080101C40B8 | 0x1006e            | Narnia                  |
+-------------+----------+--------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------+-------------------------+
| 862         | 862      | EndOfResults | 5B5724CB-E0BE-1016-0275-0080101C40B8 | 0x12d7f            | ##.##.###.###           |
+-------------+----------+--------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------+-------------------------+
| 862         | 862      | EndOfResults | 5B5724CB-E0BE-1016-0275-0080101C40B8 | 0x1006e            | Mordor                  |
+-------------+----------+--------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------+-------------------------+
| 862         | 862      | EndOfResults | 5B4AF6E5-8F8D-103E-023D-0080101C40B8 | 0x12d7f            | ##.##.###.###           |
+-------------+----------+--------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------+-------------------------+
| 862         | 862      | EndOfResults | 5B4AF6E5-8F8D-103E-023D-0080101C40B8 | 0x1006e            | Atlantis                |
+-------------+----------+--------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------+-------------------------+
```

### Use a predicate to get the needed answers

This will use a predicate within `.nodes()` to retrieve a derived table of all `<attribute>` elements, where the `@id` has a given value.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.thePlace.com')
SELECT a.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Alarm_Attribute_content
FROM @xml.nodes('//attribute[@id="0x1006e"]') A(a)
```

the result

```
Alarm_Attribute_content
------
Narnia
Mordor
Atlantis
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I tried using your SQL. It runs successfully as is but when I tried assigning the string from one record to the XML variable, I get zero results. Here are the ways I tried:

DECLARE @xml XML = (SELECT CONVERT(xml,Results) AS ContentXML FROM FREEDOMDW.waHeadendDashboard.dbo.SpectrumAlarms WHERE ID = 1)

Comment: Never mind. I found the issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

@James Pratt, I have done a mock up to give you another logic of working with loops.

This one using CTE to build up a 2000 rows (and there techniquest to expand).

```
DECLARE @Alarms table (Id int, Results varchar(max))
INSERT into @Alarms 
SELECT 1, '[A]dkdk[/A][B]123[/B][N]Fred[/N][A]ddj[/A][B]456[/B][N]Bill[/N][A]akdl[/A]...'


;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT  TOP (2000) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number)
  FROM master.dbo.spt_values ORDER BY Number
)
SELECT 
    RIGHT(t.Results, x.n) 
FROM x
    JOIN @Alarms AS t ON 
        x.n < LEN(t.Results)
```

Answer (score 0):

If open to a TVF.

Tired of extracting strings (left,right,charindex,patindex,etc), I modified a parse/split function to accept two non-like delimeters.

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = '[A]dkdk[/A][B]123[/B][N]Fred[/N][A]ddj[/A][B]456[/B][N]Bill[/N][A]akdl[/A]'

Select Seq   = A.RetSeq
      ,Item  = B.RetVal
      ,Value = A.RetVal
 From  [dbo].[tvf-str-extract](@S,']','[') A
 Join ( Select Seq=Row_Number() over (Order by RetSeq),* 
         From [dbo].[tvf-str-extract](@S,'[',']') 
         Where charindex('/',RetVal)=0
      ) B on B.Seq=A.RetSeq
 Order By A.RetSeq
```

**Returns**

```
Seq Item    Value
1   A       dkdk
2   B       123
3   N       Fred
4   A       ddj
5   B       456
6   N       Bill
7   A       akdl
```

**The Function if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  (
        Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) 
         From  cte4
       ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1

)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters
```

**Just to help with the visual, Alias A or as a standalone**

```
Select * From  [dbo].[tvf-str-extract](@S,']','[') A
```

**Returns**

```
RetSeq  RetPos  RetVal
1       4       dkdk
2       15      123
3       25      Fred
4       36      ddj
5       46      456
6       56      Bill
7       67      akdl
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a strange kind of XML... Might be not valid for all of your strings, but the given example can be transfered to XML easily:

```
DECLARE @tbl table (Id INT IDENTITY, YourString VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
('[A]dkdk[/A][B]123[/B][N]Fred[/N][A]ddj[/A][B]456[/B][N]Bill[/N][A]akdl[/A]...');

SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(t.YourString,'[','<'),']','>') AS XML)
FROM @tbl t
```

The result

```
<A>dkdk</A>
<B>123</B>
<N>Fred</N>
<A>ddj</A>
<B>456</B>
<N>Bill</N>
<A>akdl</A>...
```

It is very easy to read this part by part.

But - to be honest - there are many, many cases, where this approach would break.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the string is `VARCHAR(MAX)`, I think it should work anyway. Anyway, here's my take using a TVF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Tools.FindElements (@String VARCHAR(MAX)
                                  , @Open   VARCHAR(8000)
                                  , @Close  VARCHAR(8000))
/*
This function splits a VARCHAR string into a table of elements/items by finding opening and closing tags
The table returns ID (by the order of occurance) and String (the element)

This is based off Jeff Moden's DelimitedSplit8K function: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/
It has been modified to:
      1) Accept delimiters longer than 1 character
      2) Use two delimiters (opening and closing tags)
*/   
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  RETURN
  /* 10 rows (all 1s) */
  WITH CTE_10
       AS (SELECT Number
           FROM(VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1) ) v(Number)),
       -------------------
       /* 100 rows (all 1s) */
       CTE_100
       AS (SELECT Number = 1
           FROM CTE_10 a
                CROSS JOIN CTE_10 b),
       -------------------
       /* 10000 rows max (all 1s) */
       CTE_10000
       AS (SELECT Number = 1
           FROM CTE_100 a
                CROSS JOIN CTE_100 b),
       -------------------
       /* 100000000 rows max (all 1s) - this limits the number of elements to 100 million (which I hope is enough)) */
       CTE_100000000
       AS (SELECT Number = 1
           FROM CTE_10000 a
                CROSS JOIN CTE_10000 b),
       -------------------
       /* Numbers "Table" CTE: 
          1) TOP has variable parameter = DATALENGTH(@String)
          2) Use ROW_NUMBER */
       CTE_Numbers
       AS (SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@String), 0)) Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) )
           FROM CTE_100000000),
       -------------------
       /* Returns start of the element after each delimiter */
       CTE_Start
       AS (SELECT [Start] = Number + DATALENGTH(@Open)
           FROM CTE_Numbers
           WHERE SUBSTRING(@String, Number, DATALENGTH(@Open)) = @Open),
       -------------------
       /* IF @Delimiter <> '': Returns start and length (for use in substring) */
       CTE_Length
       AS (SELECT [Start]
                , [Length] = ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Close, @String, [Start]), 0) - [Start], 8000) -- ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
           FROM CTE_Start)


       /* Do the actual split */
       SELECT ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Start])
            , String = SUBSTRING(@String, [Start], [Length])
       FROM CTE_Length;
```

Then use it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tools.FindElements ('[A]dkdk[/A][B]123[/B][N]Fred[/N][A]ddj[/A][B]456[/B][N]Bill[/N][A]akdl[/A]', '[N]', '[/N]');
```

Or like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.TextTable
     CROSS APPLY Tools.FindElements (TextColumn, '[N]', '[/N]');
```